# linux\solaris + print specific date format from file

Tags: linux, solaris, shell-scripting, date, ls

subject -  print file date on solaris as format: yymmdd ( yy - year , mm - month , dd - day )

on Linux machine I type the following command in order to get: file date
as the following:

```
 ls -l --time-style=+%Y%m%d /etc/hosts | awk '{print $6}'
 20121107
```

.

please advice what the syntax for Solaris ? , because I get error when I try to run it on Solaris:

.

```
  ls -l --time-style=+%Y%m%d /etc/hosts
  ls: illegal option -- time-style=+%Y%m%d
```

Comment: The `ls` in solaris differs from gnu ls. So the parameter `--time-style` is not availiable in Solaris.  `man ls`  and see your options

Comment: ok but the alternative way to get the same results as I get on linux or other command/idea

Comment: is perl an option for you? i assume this has something to do with a script?

Comment: yes - but need to combine the perl in my ksh script

Comment: yes please if you have idea , I will happy to see it -:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are looking for should be:

`ls -l -T -D %Y%m%d /etc/hosts`

Hope it helps!

Another optino is to use `stat` as  `stat /ets/hosts`

See another solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839877/how-can-i-get-files-modification-date-in-ddmmyy-format-in-perl

Comment: I have solaris 10 and I get the error -     ls -l -T -D %Y%m%d /etc/hosts
ls: illegal option -- T
ls: illegal option -- D
usage: ls -1RaAdCxmnlhogrtuvVcpFbqisfHLeE@ [files]

Comment: @yael You always can install gnu `ls` on solaris and use it the same way you use it on *nix systems.

Comment: Another optino is to use `stat` as follow:

`stat /etc/hosts | awk '/Access/{print $2}' | tail -n1  | tr -d'' '-'`

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Solaris 11. The `ls` command on Solaris 11 supports the `--time-style` option.

There are tons of other reasons why Solaris 11 beats earlier versions. Just go do it.  :-)

Comment: You need to understand Stack Exchange and  Server Fault in particular better. This is a Q&A site. Someone asks a question about a problem they are experiencing at that time. Answering questions that are years old with 'Upgrade to $latestVersion' isn't really useful.

Comment: @Iain Solaris 11 was released one year before the question was asked so unixhacker2010 answer despite being late is nevertheless valid and unlike the accepted one doesn't assume Gnu ls and stat are installed on Solaris 10 which is generally not the case.

Comment: @jlliagre: My comment wasn't [just about this question though](http://serverfault.com/questions/182704/solaris-10-and-windows-shares/516566#516566). and it's still not really a useful answer when the OP says they are using [Solaris 10](http://serverfault.com/questions/452612/linux-solaris-print-specific-date-format-from-file/516574?noredirect=1#comment494032_452622).